# Does Windows 11 have “Users?” I can't find how I can add users in Windows 11 Home

Tags: windows, windows-11

I can't find how I can add users in Windows 11 Home. `Computer management` does not contain Users in `System tools`.

[image]

If I connect to this PC from another Windows machine from `computer management` I can't find any users on Windows 11 Home PC.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Windows Home does not have the apps that you can use in this way.

Go to Settings, Accounts, Other Users and add users that way. This will work.

If you wish, upgrade your version to Windows Pro to access Computer Management, Users and Groups. That is the easiest and also likely the best way.